# If "erotetic model theory" makes sense, what is its relationship to the downward Löwenheim–Skolem theorem?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, set-theory, interpretation

First, a point-of-departure [introduction to/outline of model theory:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191479/interpretation-vs-model/2191959)

> An interpretation of an axiomatic system is the assignment of meanings or values to a given axiomatic system such that all statements of said system hold true. This results in the statements of an axiomatic system being true about a "concept." This "concept" is what we shall call a **model** of the axiomatic system [emphasis added].

Let *erotetic model theory* be such that models are sets (or classes) of sentences that are relatively decisive answers to a set of questions closed under erotetic implicature. Theories are assertoric functions under erotetic ones, here. Now, we assume that the set of subquestions evoked by a completed set of answers to an erotetic set, given that the completed set has "more information in it" than the original erotetic set, is going to be the *erotetic powerset* of the previous theory's counterpoint set.

The upshot/feature-turning-back-into-a-bug, here, is that every model of a theory will automatically "evolve" into the precursor for a model of a higher theory. A set of countably many answers to a countably infinite set of questions will lead to the powerset of the zeroth aleph, in the form of a "new" set of questions. A model for these questions **must** be (at least) the size of the given erotetic set.

Or so it seems as if it might be, to me. For example, if I have an uncountable number of questions to ask, how can a countable number of answers satisfy me? There are deviant theories on either end of *V* to the effect that *cf*(*V*) < *V* (usually countable infinity, actually) (i.e. consider either ZFC - Replacement, or Paul Corazza's ["Wholeness" axiom system(s)](http://cantorsattic.info/Wholeness_axioms)); so perhaps we have an exotic means of "partitioning" *V* into countably many hyper-answers/hyper-"facts," such that chains of functions along the line of universal cofinality can variously (somehow) cover uncountable factual implicature.

I guess right now, the best (and it is not that good) that I can say is that intuitively, the erotetic powerset of a given Q&A-set must be answerable in terms of its own cardinality, and never a lesser one. But this is just intuitive for me. My question for the SE proper will be: **Is there a way to tailor the albeit so far generic concept of "erotetic model theory" to specifically block the downward Löwenheim–Skolem theorem?**

Comment: It's easy to conceive the powerset of ℵ0, however, how can "the set of subquestions evoked by a completed set of answers to an erotetic set" forming the powerset of the previous complete Q&A erotetic set act as some new syntactically correct and semantically meaningful questions? Do you have an example of such "evolved" subquestion? As for the case of having a set of uncountable questions, insofar as you have a countable cofinal set of said set is *dense* in said set you'll be satisfied since our sense perceptions of a common object are always a little different even in the countable set sense

Comment: @DoubleKnot, from what I can tell, I'll need to call in higher-order logics to do some of the work, here. This is fine by me, but at any rate, to illustrate the erotetic powerset relation, I'd have to start from finitary examples, I think. So for a set of two questions, for example, you have two immediate (complete) answers, but you also have the juxtapositions of question-satisfaction. So for example, take, "How many?" and, "Which one?" Then you have, "(A) answers to neither; (B) answers to one; (C) answers to the other; (D) answers to both." Voila(?)! The erotetic powerset of 2?

Comment: ...continue my previous comment only. So your rule-following-precision-like understanding of your decisive answer will always a little different from the understanding of the answerer, so with this philosophy will you still insist to understand those remaining potentially non-well-orderable uncountable questions? The downward and upward LS theorems reminded us countability as a basic math property is not *absolute* in first order theories and Skolem's paradox is not really an issue but a novel feature of first order set theory, so to block it you simply have to invoke higher-order logics...

Comment: @DoubleKnot, indeed, the "moral of the story" is that there is a limit on knowable/understandable, and hence belief-justifiable, cardinals. I'm assuming for now that this limit is lost in the maze of the Icarus sets somewhere, and so that the fully choiceless cardinals beyond have a lesser *degree of existence* than the choiceful hierarchy, notwithstanding that we can also positively *quantify over* the Reinhardt, Berkeley, and future such sets. "Ideally," as the choiceless hierarchy approaches the limit of *V*, the degree of existence of its ranks goes to zero.

Comment: @DoubleKnot, in surreal/surdinal terms, then, we set *S* = *V* for the surreal transet (proper class), and allow *S* - *x*, for all *x*. A descending transet appears for *S* - 1, *S* - 2, ... *S* - omega, *S* - (omega + 1) ... etc., all the way to *S* - *S* = 0. The smallest choiceless set either retains a degree of existence *S*, or goes to *S* - 1, etc. until the vanishing tail of the choiceless sets goes to *S* - *S* = 0. Alt., the first omega-many choiceless sets are such as omega - 1, omega - 2, etc. and there are choiceless ranks based on higher omegas layered as such.

Comment: The choiceless very large cardinals is similar to the situation in 2nd order logic set theory AC cannot deduce well-ordering, there're simply so many sets that only a partial order could possibly exist. Btw it's ironic that finitist Skolem didn't believe in any uncountable set till his death while upward LS theorem bears his name... As for your example since most logics are *monotonic*, a decisive answer to any question could be *safely added* to any other answer of another question even it may be irrelevant! Thus naive combinatorics won't actually form a meaningful powerset as you wished...

Comment: Above conclusion is also consistent with the epistemic intuition pump that there should be much less answers than questions, otherwise why one needs to learn philosophy! If there exists a theory of everything then there's just one answer to all questions there possibly were, are, and will be...